# StringBuffer append("")

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currentlly refactoring an application using a lot of this:

```
StringBuffer buff1 = new StringBuffer("");

buff1.append("some value A");
buff1.append("");
buff1.append("some value B");
```

The coder that made those code lines didn't seems to be an idiot, is there any reasons I can't see to use the append("") to a StringBuffer?

Comment: Does the output text now appear like "some value Asome value B" so t is now unreadable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely that code was generated by some refactoring tool and the coder wasn't bothered to remove the redundant lines.

Comment: Gotta love variable names like `buff1`.

Answer (score 5):

Nope.

And given that they're hardcoded strings, it'd be identical to write

```
buff1 = new StringBuffer("some value Asome value B");
```

BTW, it's a bit more efficient to use a StringBuilder rather than a StringBuffer (and the API is identical).

Comment: it isn't, but how often do you modify the same StringBuffer instance between different threads?

Comment: Yes, but almost always you use it locally in a single thread so you don't need thread safety.

Comment: I was giving the hardcoded String as an example... Because, as I said, it is used in a lot of different situations in the app. And yes, it is used in a Process integration server, in a multi thread situation needing thread safe.

Comment: Just because you are using the StringBuffer in a multithreaded application doesn't mean you have to use thread-safe data structures. It only needs to be thread safe if the same instance is shared by multiple threads.

Answer (score 4):

No you don't need that `append("")`. You also do not need to initialize the StringBuffer with a String. `new StringBuffer();` will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no further appends made to the StringBuffer the code should be rewritten as

```
String buff1 = "some value some value B";
```

This is more concise, more readable and safer than:

```
StringBuffer buff1 = new StringBuffer("");

buff1.append("some value A");
buff1.append("some value B");
```

I say 'safer' because a String is immutable and a StringBuffer is immutable, so there's no risk of the String accidentally being changed after construction.

---

**Aside**

It's a common misconception that "concatenating Strings in Java is bad". While it's true that you shouldn't write code like this

```
String buff1 = "foo";    
buff1 += "some value A";
buff1 += "some value B";
```

It's perfectly acceptable to write code like this:

```
String buff1 = "foo" + "some value A" + "some value B";
```

when the concatenation is performed in a single statement the code will be optimized to:

```
String buff1 = "foo some value A some value B";
```

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler be able to rewrite that concatenation of literals as a single literal? There would be no observable difference at run-time.

Comment: Yes, per JLS Section 3.10.5, *String Literals*, such a constant expression is rewritten as a single *interned* string.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of why he'd do that is readability (though even that seems a bit strange).

Comment: I consider `String buff1 = "some value A some value B";` a lot more readable than the above

Answer (score 0):

He probably meant to put `buff1.append(" ");`. Just my take.

Answer (score 0):

buff1.append("") is irrelevant and should be removed.